# Add repository url to install_requires in project's setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm developing a django app which depends on an app in a private
bitbucket repository, for example ssh:/...@bitbucket.org/username/my-django-app.
is it possible to add this url to the list of install_requires in my
setup.py? tried various possibilities, but none worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this with setuptools, but it's possible with distribute (wich can be consider as the new setuptools). Check [Dependencies that aren’t in PyPI sections in distribute documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi).